# ASP.NET 4.0 URL Routing HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: routes, asp.net-4.0

I have implemented URL routing in ASP.NET 4.0 using following route.

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
   "NewsDetails",               // Route name
   "news/{i}/{*n}",  // Route URL
   "~/newsdetails.aspx"      // Web page to handle route
    );
```

which gives me url like

```
http://www.mysie.com/news/1/this-is-test-news
```

and this is working in my localhost fine.

But when I uploaded it on the server it gives ...

```
Server Error

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, 
or is temporarily unavailable.
```

If I try http://www.mysie.com/news/1/this-is-test-news.aspx then it displays page.

Has anyone have same problem?

How can i set URL 
http://www.mysie.com/news/1/this-is-test-news  to work on windows server 2008 ?

Comment: Is the file with the route in the same directory as that of the aspx page?

Comment: no. my aspx files are at root folder

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To enable default ASP.Net 4.0 routing with IIS 7.5:

1. Make sure that you have installed the **HTTP Redirection feature**
   It can be done -> Control Panel -> Progams -> Turn off windows features -> World wide web Services -> Common HTTP Features -> HTTP Redirection
2. Modify your `web.config` with the code below

```
<system.webServer>   
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">    
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" 
             type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" 
             preCondition="integratedMode" 
             verb="*" 
             path="UrlRouting.axd" 
             type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

3. Create Routes in your `global.asax` file

> Note:  You have to set Application Pool to **Asp.net 4.0 application pool** , as routing is not working with ***Asp.net 4.0 Classic Application pool.***

Hope this will help.

Comment: Is this really supposed to say `UrlRoutingHandler 2.0.0.0`? why wouldn't it be 4.0?

Comment: This worked for me, but I did not need to add the UrlRoutingHandler node.

Comment: I'm running into something similar, but this asnwer did not work, could you have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080141/routeconfig-file-throws-404-when-routing-urls-multiple-levels-deep

Answer (score 1):

I've read all your recipes but my web site (**ASP.NET 4.0 + VS2010 + Cassini**) was still not **routing** correctly.

The **Virtual Path** for my site was "CompanyName.ApplicationName.Web". I changed this virtual to "MyApplicationName" and voila!

Change the Cassini's Virtual Path configuration:

- Cassini's Virtual Path -> Ctrl + W, P or;
- Right click the Web Site and "Properties Window".

Comment: So glad I found this answer! I  was using a virtual path that had a period "." in it. After changing my virtual path from "mysite.com" to "mysite", all my custom routing worked.

Answer (score 1):

My solution, after trying EVERYTHING:

Bad deployment, an old **PrecompiledApp.config** was hanging around my deploy location, and making everything not work.

My final settings that worked:

- IIS 7.5, Win2k8r2 x64,
- Integrated mode application pool
- *Nothing changes in the web.config* - this means no special handlers for routing. Here's my snapshot of the sections a lot of other posts reference. I'm using FluorineFX, so I do have that handler added, but I did not need any others:

  ```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="None"/>

    <pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>

    <httpModules>
      <add name="FluorineGateway" type="FluorineFx.FluorineGateway, FluorineFx"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <!-- Modules for IIS 7.0 Integrated mode -->
      <modules>
        <add name="FluorineGateway" type="FluorineFx.FluorineGateway, FluorineFx" />
      </modules>

      <!-- Disable detection of IIS 6.0 / Classic mode ASP.NET configuration -->
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    </system.webServer>
  ```
- Global.ashx: (only method of any note)

  ```
  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      // Register routes...
      System.Web.Routing.Route echoRoute = new System.Web.Routing.Route(
            "{*message}",
          //the default value for the message
            new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary() { { "message", "" } },
          //any regular expression restrictions (i.e. @"[^\d].{4,}" means "does not start with number, at least 4 chars
            new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary() { { "message", @"[^\d].{4,}" } },
            new TestRoute.Handlers.PassthroughRouteHandler()
         );

      System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Add(echoRoute);
  }
  ```
- PassthroughRouteHandler.cs - this achieved an automatic conversion from http://andrew.arace.info/stackoverflow to http://andrew.arace.info/#stackoverflow which would then be handled by the default.aspx:

  ```
  public class PassthroughRouteHandler : IRouteHandler {

      public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) {
          HttpContext.Current.Items["IncomingMessage"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["message"];
          requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("#" + HttpContext.Current.Items["IncomingMessage"], true);
          return null;
      }
  }
  ```