# What's the proper configuration or routing so that Default.aspx, "", and "~/" don't get routed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-4.0, webforms

I've got glimpse.

it's highlighting an empty line on the routes tab

`Match Area Url Data constraints DataTokens`

`True  Root  -- --`

Locally it seems cassini doesn't properly emulate a virtual directory so changing from `localhost` to `localhost/site` doesn't seem to grant any additional testing insight.

- Local testing

  - cassini (windows 7 (32 and 64 bit are available))
  - doesn't seem to use or allow integrated
- deploy environments

  - IIS7 Integrated
  - Tried a http routing setting to push `/` to `/site` however I ran into trailing slash issues (`/site` would route to `/site/site`, while `/site/` would work as expected
- web.config

  - tried a few ways of setting `runAllManagedModules=false` with various errors
  - using `<remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />` that was [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523264/asp-net-4-0-url-routing-http-error-404-0-not-found)
- tried

I need `/site` (`/~`) requests to go to **`~/Default.aspx`**
would love for a way to have `/` go there as well.

How do I do it?

Comment: I'd love to try to help you, but I've read this 3 times and I'm still not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish.  Can you clarify at all?

Comment: aspx and mvc pages living in harmony. on a virtual path that is not root. where appRoot calls would be directed to the default .aspx page not the home controller

Answer (score 0):

To enable `Default.aspx` as the default url you just need to remove your route handling so that there's no catch-all route.

By default all MVC 3 projects have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

This is a catch-all route that will match *everything* you pass in your url. If you remove this and no path is defined then it will use whatever you set up as your default page in your `web.config`.

To map `/site` to `Default.aspx` you just need to add a special route:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("SitetoDefault", "site", "~/Default.aspx");
```

This will see the `/site` and route it to your default page.

You'll have to be careful when adding any other routes to your routing table. All of them will have to have a controller defined or you'll have to add a routing constraint. Something like this:

```
//controller defined
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

//route constraint
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }, // Parameter defaults
    new { controller = "^(products)|(account)|(home)$" }
);
```

Here is more detail on creating more complex routing: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs

Comment: so then mvc can't handle my 404's and use default.aspx as it's default page?