# URL Routing with ASP.NET 4 Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-routing

I have ASP.NET webFroms application on my local, when i try to use this following rout I get 404 not found error. I am trying to go to mylocalsite.com/home that should resolve to ~/Default.aspx, what can be the issue? I did try many ways and followed on MSDN help on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202.aspx but cant make it to work so that I can create the routs that i need. the site is running on IIS7.

this following code is in my Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {

            routes.MapPageRoute("homepage", "/home", "~/Default.aspx");

        }

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all of your help, and I finally found what was my exact problem, you can see it in below link, my main issue was HTTP Redirection feature was not enabled in windows features --> World wide web Services --> Common HTTP Features --> HTTp Redirection

full steps for fix:
[ASP.NET 4.0 URL Routing HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523264/asp-net-4-0-url-routing-http-error-404-0-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

A route cannot start with `/`. Try:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("homepage", "home", "~/Default.aspx");
```

Also make sure that your application pool is configured to run in Integrated Pipeline mode in IIS 7.0 in order for extensionless urls such as `/home` to work.

Comment: I did try without /, but still the same issue, also could you please tell me how should I configure Integrated Pipeline mode in IIS 7? because I did some search and came many ways of configuration on this so not sure which one exactly you mean?

Comment: @NazoTajrian, take a look here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd441157(v=office.13).aspx

Comment: Hey Darin, yes I thing this is one of my issues, I have my application in classic pipeline mode but when I switch to Integrated I get an error:

HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

I think the issue is related to web.config maybe? I am currently searching for this error Error 500.22 but meanwhile if you know any about this can you tell me? or any suggestions how to fix to run on Integrated mode?

Comment: @NazoTajrian, which setting is the error referring to? Be aware that in integrated pipeline mode you don't have access to an HttpContext in the Application_Start method so any attempt to access some of its properties might fail.

Comment: Hi, yes that was the issue in my Application_Start but what will be alternative of Application_Start to use if there is? I was just loading some files from folder in Application_Start

Comment: @NazoTajrian, you can use Application_Start in integrated mode. What you cannot use is access to HttpContext. Depending on what exactly are you trying to achieve there are alternatives. You mention something about files, so I guess you are trying to find the physical location to those files. So instead of for example using `Server.MapPath` you could use `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath` to get the root physical path of your site and from there `Path.Combine` to reach the desired location.

Comment: I made my application to work in Integrated mode and just for now commented all of my code in Application_Start i can figure that out later no problem, I have my route setup as :

routes.MapPageRoute("homepage", "home", "~/Default.aspx");

but still can't make this route to work, I still get "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" error when i goto mylocalsitename.com/home

by the way this is hosted on my local

Comment: By the way, i did try one thing and it worked, I created new ASP.NET Application project in VS2010 and added the same route there then I did right click on default.aspx to run in browser which will creat visual development server like http://localhot:xxxx/ and this way the routing worked good, so the only differences is that the application I have the routing is not working if is setup on IIS but it is working if I run from visual studio what will the reason can be for this to act like that? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Second argument to MapPageRoute method is The URL pattern for the route, which is the path that you see after server/application name, you should not specify "/" for it.