# Asp.net routing with file Extension

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-routing

I would like to use routing to caching to client webbrowsers dynamic images generated.

I have created this routing code for .Net 4.0

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
routes.MapPageRoute("ImageWithLogo", "imageWithLogo/{Id}/{Width}/{Height}/image.jpg", "~/utils/imageWithLogo.aspx");
```

Trying this for example "imageWithLogo/1623/100/200/image.jpg" I always get the error Error HTTP 404.0 - Not Found, IIS always try to find the imageFile in web folder.

How can i make that IIS don't try to find the file in the web folders and always apply the routing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I have find the solution in another Question in stackoverflow [ASP.NET 4.0 URL Routing HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523264/asp-net-4-0-url-routing-http-error-404-0-not-found)